# Deploying Angular 2 tutorial webpack build

Tags: angularjs, angular, webpack

I am currently trying to learn ng2.

I have followed the tutorial here : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html

And have found creating a dist of my build, upon attempting to run it, both locally and on Github Pages, I am receiving a 404 error on my bundle files.

I have followed the tutorial line for line and it does not appear to be working.

Can anyone help?

My webpack build is as follows :

**webpack.common.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
        'vendor': './src/vendor.ts',
        'app': './src/main.ts'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
    },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
                loader: 'file?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap')
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
                loader: 'raw'
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
        }),

        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/index.html'
        })
    ]
};
```

webpack.prod.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.ENV = 'production';

module.exports = webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
    devtool: 'source-map',

    output: {
        path: helpers.root('dist'),
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: '[name].[hash].js',
        chunkFilename: '[id].[hash].chunk.js'
    },

    htmlLoader: {
        minimize: false // workaround for ng2
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ // https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10618
            mangle: {
                keep_fnames: true
            }
        }),
        new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].[hash].css'),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                'ENV': JSON.stringify(ENV)
            }
        })
    ]
});
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <base href=/>
    <title>Angular With Webpack</title>
    <meta charset=UTF-8>
    <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link href="/app.f053dbe7ce9dd32c3e43.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/polyfills.f053dbe7ce9dd32c3e43.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor.f053dbe7ce9dd32c3e43.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/app.f053dbe7ce9dd32c3e43.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem! Do you have karma.conf.js in config dir? Your project structure should be like :
[image]

Comment: Hey - I do yes, I've been playing around and it looks like it is related to the         publicPath: '/', in my webpack file - also it looks like the "" are being stripped from index.html base href.

Not sure why / how to fix this yet

Comment: look at my project: https://github.com/dmaric444/angular2webpackstarter.git

Comment: after download or git clone type npm install then npm start and then browse to localhost:8080